# gaussian class in java

Tags: java, class, void, gaussian

I am making a class that simulates a Gaussian integer.  I am using a constructor in my addition method to add two the two parts of the gInt and then return a new gInt that is the sum.  But for some reason when I am trying to implement this method, Java says that a gInt is required when I initialize the new gInt and that it found a void.  Why would this be? I have included the class below and indicated what line causes this error.

```
public class gInt {

    private int real;
    private int imag;



    public void gInt(int r)
    {
        imag=0;
        real=r;

    }

    public void gInt(int r, int i)
    {
        real=r;
        imag=i;

    }

    gInt add(gInt rhs)
    {
        gInt added;
        int nReal=this.real+rhs.real;
        int nImag=this.imag+rhs.real;

        added= gInt(nReal,nImag);   //--> Says it requires a gInt and found a void

        return added;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this implementation and all will be happy:

```
public class GInt {

    private int real;
    private int imag;

    public GInt(int r) {
        imag=0;
        real=r;
    }

    public GInt(int r, int i) {
        real = r;
        imag = i;
    }

    GInt add(GInt rhs) {
        GInt added;
        int nReal = this.real + rhs.real;
        int nImag = this.imag + rhs.real;

        added = new GInt(nReal, nImag);

        return added;
    }
}
```

**Comments:**

- Don't use class names which begin with a lowercase letter (e.g. `gInt` instead of `GInt`)
- Constructors in Java do not have a return type in Java, so I removed the `void` type in the OP
- You need the `new` operator to create a new `GInt` object in Java

Comment: You mistyped "GInt" as "Gnt" in the second constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You **don't specify the return type on the constructor** of your class. Your constructors should look like this instead:

```
public gInt(int r)
{
    imag=0;
    real=r;

}

public gInt(int r, int i)
{
    real=r;
    imag=i;

}
```

Note how I removed the `void` in front of the methods' names.

When you create a new instance of your class, you also have to **use the `new` keyword**:

```
added= new gInt(nReal,nImag);
```

For more info on how to create objects in Java, [have a look at the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

constructed function can't use the `void`, and use `added = new gInt(nReal,nImag);`
maybe you don't like that, you can use `added = new gInt.gInt(nReal,nImag);` gInt is an object, you need to create, then you can use the object!

Comment: What does `added = new gInt.gInt(nReal,nImag);` mean? Does it work?